# Xml Dom parsing returning null

Tags: javascript, xml

I am new to html and javascript. I have been trying to parse and access the data of an xml file through the javascript code. Presently it is showing null. I am posting my codes below. Please have a look and do help.

```
    Html code:

        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <body>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
    var xhttp;
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            myFunction(this);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "http://10.21.64.222/LoadBreakSwitch/LBS_Commands.xml", true);
    xhttp.send();

    function myFunction(xml) {
        var x, i, txt, xmlDoc; 
        xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
        txt = "";
        x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Ping");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
            txt += x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>

The xml file:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LBSCommands>
  <Ping Commkey="A3070000AA00A4" Value="A309008001043101A4"/>
  <Frequency Commkey="A3070300AD00A4" CommValue="A309038001013101A4"/>
  <SwitchStatus Commkey="A3071D01C800A4" CommValue="A3091D8101014C01A4"/>

</LBSCommands>
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. You're accessing the nodeValue of `"Ping"` which is null. You probably want to do `getAttribute("Commkey")` or `getAttribute("Value")` instead of `nodeValue`. if you want to get the nodeValue, your Ping should be something like `<Ping Commkey="A3070000AA00A4" Value="A309008001043101A4">my ping</Ping>`, the nodeValue would then be `"my ping"`.

Comment: @phoa- thank you for replying. But even after using getAttribute, errors are coming.

Comment: I meant `txt += x[i].getAttribute('Value') + "<br>"`

Comment: @phoa- thank you..:)

Comment: @phoa: can you please tell me how to update the value in the xml file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "it is showing null", but maybe changing your code to using `onload` callback would help:

```
var xhttp;
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onload = function() {
    myFunction(this);
};
```

Also, this line: `txt += x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";` will throw an exception since `childNodes[0]` is `undefined` in your XML document.

**EDIT:**

To make `x[i].childNodes[0]` non-null, you must move the desired attribute to be the child element's text value. For instance, if you replace:

```
<Ping Commkey="A3070000AA00A4" Value="A309008001043101A4"/>
```

with:

```
<Ping>
    <Commkey key="A3070000AA00A4">
        A309008001043101A4
    <Commkey/>
<Ping/>
```

(and do the same to the rest of the elements) then you'll have something like:

```
 <p id="demo">
      A309008001043101A4<br>
      A309038001013101A4<br>
      A3091D8101014C01A4<br>
 </p>
```

as your HTML.

If that's not the exact HTML outcome you want please show an example HTML so I'll be able to help.

Comment: @Elist- Is there any way I can make the childNodes[0]  valid here?